# Problem with ellipsesize

Tags: android, textview, ellipse

I have a TextView I use to display email addresses to my users

```
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/profile_email"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />
```

My issue is that many email addresses get cut off in the middle instead of having an ellipse at the end.  Here is an example:

If my email address is

```
short.name@mydomain.com
```

everything works fine.  However, If my email address is

```
really.longfreakennameforanemailaddressandscreenisntwideenough@mydomain.com
```

the only thing that will display is

```
really.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can use :

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```